# Selecting specific MySQL row occurences on which to calculate an average

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a MySQL table containing that tracks user session start & end times:

```
UserId      Start                   End
150392  2012-07-11 01:11:28 2012-07-11 01:17:36
150392  2012-07-11 01:19:03 2012-07-11 01:23:47
150393  2012-07-11 01:22:47 2012-07-11 01:38:15
150051  2012-07-11 01:31:03 2012-07-11 01:36:07
150393  2012-07-11 01:37:43 2012-07-11 01:56:41
150392  2012-07-11 01:48:57 2012-07-11 01:54:23
```

I want to be able to retrieve average session times **based on the number of times users have entered our system**. To clarify, I'd like to know the average session time for users the first time they enter our system, the average session time the second time in our system, etc. So the first time a userid appears in the table, that's a users first session; We sum the session time on all those first time occurrences and divide by the count. Then do the same for 2nd time userid occurrences and get the average time, etc.

Using the table above as an example the average time for 3rd session would be 326 seconds, as only one user has a 3rd session (userID 150392, last row).

So I'm looking for an output something like this:

```
SessionCount    AvgTime (seconds)
1               540
2               810
3               326
```

I hope that makes sense. Any advice would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Please don't cross post questions on multiple sites. This has been posted on DBA.SE -- http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30931/select-specific-table-row-occurences-on-which-to-calculate-an-average Please pick one site to post your question on.

Comment: To be clear, you want the average time of _that particular session index_, for all users... This would be much easier with a `ROW_NUMBER()` (or related) function.  What should happen if users have concurrent sessions (however they got them...)?  Or should it just be strictly by `start`?

Comment: @bluefeet can we move it from DBA.SE to here and merge it or something?

Comment: @bonCodigo the OP would have to flag it on DBA and request a mod to move it

Comment: I deleted the other post - Apologies.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: You are correct - Average session time across all users for a particular session index. Concurrent session, while not impossible, generally won't occur. On the odd occasion that they do, we can just count the later session as the next session.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SessionCount, AVG(duration) AS AvgTime FROM (
  SELECT   COUNT(*) AS SessionCount,
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t2.Start, t2.End) AS duration
  FROM     my_table t1
      JOIN my_table t2
        ON t1.UserId = t2.UserId AND t1.Start <= t2.Start
  GROUP BY t2.UserId, t2.Start, t2.End
) t GROUP BY SessionCount
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52276/3/0).